# How can I put my overlay div *above* the Facebook Like button?

Tags: html, css, facebook

I am fading in a hidden div as an overlay div (with jQuery). It appears above all elements of my page, except the Facebook Like button.

I tried `z-index: 100;` in CSS but it didn't work.

Anyone had that problem?

PS: Same thing happens with the Twitter button, but not with the Google +1 button

```
    <fb:like href="http://www.apple.com" send="true" layout="button_count" 
width="450" show_faces="false"></fb:like>
```

Comment: Which version of the Facebook like button are you using, XHTML, HTML5 or iframe?

Comment: Hi, Im using XFBML. I put my code in the OP. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, this seems to make sense, considering the twitter and Facebook button will use JS to create their buttons.

Because the JS will run client side after all your styles have loaded, it can always overwrite any attempts to cover it up.

I actually think covering up the facebook like button might be against the TOS but you will need to check into that.

Things to try

**Encompassing Div**

Create a div around it, with the appropriate z-index.

**Correct z-index**

Make sure the FB and Twitter buttons aren't creating z-index's greater than yours. While z-index technically only goes from 0-255 (i think), people go negative and above 255 to make sure they are the highest or lowest.

**JavaScript**

After the buttons have loaded, use JS to set the z-index or other properties to hide

Comment: Hi Adam, thanks for your response. I will try that and will get back to you. Regards